# ng-repeat is not getting executed if i use JQuery code in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to execute the below code and iam not getting the desired output. I need to validate the start date and end date and the program start and end should be between actual start date and end date. now i got the output for date validation , but the ng-repeat code is not working.Kindly help me in this.

```
enter code here
     <!doctype html>
     <html>
     <head>
     Resource Tracker
     </head>
     <title>
     Resource Tracker
     </title>

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
     type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
     rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>

     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
                 $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
                     onSelect: function (selected) {
                         var dt = new Date(selected);
                         dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                        $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                        $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                        $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);

                     }
                 });

                 $("#pgmFrom").datepicker({
                     onSelect: function (selected) {
                         var dt = new Date(selected);
                         dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                         $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                     }
                 });

                $("#pgmTo").datepicker({
                     onSelect: function (selected) {
                         var dt = new Date(selected);
                         dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                         $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                     }
                 });

                 $("#txtTo").datepicker({
                     onSelect: function (selected) {
                         var dt = new Date(selected);
                         dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                        $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                        $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                     }
                 });


             });


     var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
     app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.employeeDetails = [

             ];

             $scope.addNew = function(employeeDetail){
                 $scope.employeeDetails.push({ 
                     'empid': "", 
                     'fname': "",
                     'lname': "",
                    'stream':"",
                    'location':"",
                    'resourcetype':"",
                    'programname':"",
                    'ssstartdate':"",
                    'programstartdate':"",
                    'programenddate':"",
                    'releasedate':""
                 });
             };

             $scope.remove = function(){
                 var newDataList=[];
                 $scope.selectedAll = false;
                 angular.forEach($scope.employeeDetails, function(selected){
                     if(!selected.selected){
                         newDataList.push(selected);
                     }
                 }); 
                 $scope.employeeDetails = newDataList;
             };

         $scope.checkAll = function () {
             if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
                 $scope.selectedAll = true;
             } else {
                 $scope.selectedAll = false;
             }
             angular.forEach($scope.employeeDetails, function(employeeDetail) {
                 employeeDetail.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
             });
         }; 
     }]);
     </script>
     <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ListController">     
         <div class="container">
                             <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                                 <table class="table" style="width: 100%">
                                     <thead>
                                         <tr style="width:100%">
                                             <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>

                                            <th>Employee Id</th>
                                             <th>Firstname</th>
                                             <th>Lastname</th>
                                            <th>Stream</th>
                                            <th>Location</th>
                                            <th>Resource Type</th>
                                            <th>Program Name</th>
                                            <th>SS Start Date</th>
                                            <th>Program Start Date</th>
                                            <th>Program End Date</th>
                                            <th>Release Date</th>
                                         </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody ng-repeat="employeeDetail in employeeDetails">
                                         <tr>
                                             <td >
                                                 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="employeeDetail.selected"/></td>

                                             <td>
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.empid" maxlength="6" /></td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.fname" /></td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.lname" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.stream" />
                                                         <option value="O2A">O2A</option>
                                                         <option value="billing">Billing</option>
                                                         <option value="TOSCA">TOSCA</option>
                                                         <option value="NFT">NFT</option>
                                                 </select>
                                                <td>
                                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.location" />
                                                         <option value="onshore">Onshore</option>
                                                         <option value="offshore">OffShore</option>
                                                 </select>
                                                 </td>
                                                <td>
                                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.resourcetype" />
                                                         <option value="core">Core</option>
                                                         <option value="hold">Hold</option>
                                                 </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programname" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                 <input type="text" id="txtFrom" class="form-control" pick-a-date="curDate" ng-model="employeeDetail.ssstartdate" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                 <input type="text" id="pgmFrom"class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programstartdate" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                 <input type="text" id="pgmTo" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programenddate" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtTo" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.releasedate" /></td>

                                         </tr>
                                     </tbody>
                                 </table>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input ng-hide="!employeeDetails.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="-">
                                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="+">
                                 </div>
                             </form>
         </div>
     </body>
     <html>
```

Comment: Did you check your console error.

Comment: yeah Kumar. Its showing 'Uncaught reference error:Angular is not defined'

Comment: first , Angular not defined issue happen two times... First your angular js library file not include in header or ... something went wrong in code. check you have already add js library file or link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: whatever the code i pasted in the space, the same code i used.....when iam including the angular library..i cannot see the JQuery code executed...with out angular library..iam getting that Jquery code running properly...could you please suggest me the changes need to be done in the code so that it will run ng-repeat and the satrtdate end date validation properly.

Comment: One more thing .. Just remove your jquery code.. and works only with angular js .. Is this working fine???

Comment: yes...its working fine ....induvidually both the codes are working fine but when i include one code,the other is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
     <head>
     Resource Tracker
     </head>
     <title>
     Resource Tracker
     </title>

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
         rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
         type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function () {
                         $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
                             onSelect: function (selected) {
                                 var dt = new Date(selected);
                                 dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                                $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                                $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                                $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);

                             }
                         });

                         $("#pgmFrom").datepicker({
                             onSelect: function (selected) {
                                 var dt = new Date(selected);
                                 dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                                 $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                             }
                         });

                        $("#pgmTo").datepicker({
                             onSelect: function (selected) {
                                 var dt = new Date(selected);
                                 dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                                 $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                             }
                         });

                         $("#txtTo").datepicker({
                             onSelect: function (selected) {
                                 var dt = new Date(selected);
                                 dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                                $("#pgmFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                                $("#pgmTo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                             }
                         });


                     });


             var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
             app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
                 $scope.employeeDetails = [

                     ];

                     $scope.addNew = function(employeeDetail){
                         $scope.employeeDetails.push({ 
                             'empid': "", 
                             'fname': "",
                             'lname': "",
                            'stream':"",
                            'location':"",
                            'resourcetype':"",
                            'programname':"",
                            'ssstartdate':"",
                            'programstartdate':"",
                            'programenddate':"",
                            'releasedate':""
                         });
                     };

                     $scope.remove = function(){
                         var newDataList=[];
                         $scope.selectedAll = false;
                         angular.forEach($scope.employeeDetails, function(selected){
                             if(!selected.selected){
                                 newDataList.push(selected);
                             }
                         }); 
                         $scope.employeeDetails = newDataList;
                     };

                 $scope.checkAll = function () {
                     if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
                         $scope.selectedAll = true;
                     } else {
                         $scope.selectedAll = false;
                     }
                     angular.forEach($scope.employeeDetails, function(employeeDetail) {
                         employeeDetail.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
                     });
                 }; 
             }]);
             </script>
             <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ListController">     
                 <div class="container">
                                     <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                                         <table class="table" style="width: 100%">
                                             <thead>
                                                 <tr style="width:100%">
                                                     <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>

                                                    <th>Employee Id</th>
                                                     <th>Firstname</th>
                                                     <th>Lastname</th>
                                                    <th>Stream</th>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                    <th>Resource Type</th>
                                                    <th>Program Name</th>
                                                    <th>SS Start Date</th>
                                                    <th>Program Start Date</th>
                                                    <th>Program End Date</th>
                                                    <th>Release Date</th>
                                                 </tr>
                                             </thead>
                                             <tbody>
                                                 <tr ng-repeat="employeeDetail in employeeDetails">
                                                     <td >
                                                         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="employeeDetail.selected"/></td>

                                                     <td>
                                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.empid" maxlength="6" /></td>
                                                     <td>
                                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.fname" /></td>
                                                     <td>
                                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.lname" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.stream" />
                                                                 <option value="O2A">O2A</option>
                                                                 <option value="billing">Billing</option>
                                                                 <option value="TOSCA">TOSCA</option>
                                                                 <option value="NFT">NFT</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.location" />
                                                                 <option value="onshore">Onshore</option>
                                                                 <option value="offshore">OffShore</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                         </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.resourcetype" />
                                                                 <option value="core">Core</option>
                                                                 <option value="hold">Hold</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programname" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                         <input type="text" id="txtFrom" class="form-control" pick-a-date="curDate" ng-model="employeeDetail.ssstartdate" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                         <input type="text" id="pgmFrom"class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programstartdate" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                         <input type="text" id="pgmTo" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.programenddate" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <input type="text" id="txtTo" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeDetail.releasedate" /></td>

                                                 </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                         </table>

                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <input ng-hide="!employeeDetails.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="-">
                                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="+">
                                         </div>
                                     </form>
                 </div>
             </body>
             <html>
```

Comment: In the code you have pasted, you haven't included the angular.js file. So that is why ng-repeat cannot run because it is part of angular. First include jquery file and then include angular file. And then run the code again

Comment: hatever the code i pasted in the space, the same code i used.....when iam including the angular library..i cannot see the JQuery code executed...with out angular library..iam getting that Jquery code running properly...could you please suggest me the changes need to be done in the code so that it will run ng-repeat and the satrtdate end date validation properly.

Comment: I have tested it and the problem with your code is that you are initializing elements in document.ready function which does not exist in DOM yet. If you see the elements are added when you press the + button. So I have done the part on that function as well but no gain. Because Jquery UI is not syncing with angular. The best approach will be to use a jquery UI datepicker that has a layer of angular on it. Here is one. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date